# Extending a holomorphic map on diffeomorphic affine varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Suppose I have two smooth complex affine varieties $X$ and $Y$.  Assume that they are each diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ (where $n\geq 3$).

> **Question:** If there exists open dense subsets $U\subset X$ and $V\subset Y$ such that $U$ is biholomophic to $V$, does there exist an extension to a biholomorphism between $X$ and $Y$?

Given that [Hartog's Extension Theorem](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Hartogs_theorem) seems to give an affirmative answer when $X\setminus U$ is compact, I suspect that answer is no since $X\setminus U$ is not necessarily compact in this setting.

**Natural generalizations:** More generally, one can remove the assumption that $X$ and $Y$ are diffeomorphic to affine space and simply ask that they are diffeomorphic.  Also, one can weaken the hypothesis that $X$, $Y$ are complex affine varieties and assume instead they are Stein manifolds.

**Motivation:** Given that [exotic affine spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exotic_affine_space) need not be biholomorphic (see this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/132062/12218), its [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/132337/12218), and the main [reference](https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9506005.pdf)), an affirmative answer here would imply that there exist exotic affine spaces that are not birational.

This would potentially answer this [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/301249/12218) if one can show that equality in the Grothendieck ring would imply birationallity in this context (as suggested in the comments).

**Remark:** Regardless of the motivation, this question, and its generalizations, seem to me might be of independent interest, so I decided to post it separately.  However, as I am not an analyst, I worry that I am asking a question with a trivial counter-example.  Apologies if that is the case.